# Try to FIlter by Condition, but get an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am very new to python. But I try to filter by "cert" but it only returns an empty data frame but with the right column titles.

[image]

here is the code

```
filter =  Net_Income_df['cert']==480228
temp_df = Net_Income_df[filter]
temp_df
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is the cert column type ints or strings. I have a feeling they are strings: `Net_Income_df['cert']=='480228'` Also, do not use filter as a variable because you are overwriting the built-in function.

Comment: Hi, they are ints! I also used `loc` but it is also not giving me anything....Could it be because that I did not clean my data properly?

Comment: are you sure there is a row with that cert value?
Maybe check  `(Net_Income_df['cert']==480228).any() is True`